How to left-align section titles in Revtex4-2
I'm using the following setup for an article:
\documentclass[prd,amsmath,superscriptaddress,twocolumn,eqsecnum,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\pdfoutput=1

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}
{\centering}
{\raggedright}
{}
{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}
{\centering}
{\raggedright}
{}
{}

\makeatletter
\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\def\p@subsection{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{This is a very lengthy section title that takes up more than one line}

\section{Here's another rather lengthy section title that takes up more than one line}

This is the desired output:

\section{This is a very lengthy section title that \newline \hspace*{6.95mm} takes up more than one line}

\section{Here's another rather lengthy section \newline \hspace*{6.25mm} title that takes up more than one line}


\end{document}

I'm wondering how I can modify the code that follows the "\patchcmd" command such that section titles that are long enough to be split across multiple lines are automatically left-aligned as indicated in the desired output of the MWE above.

Hi there! Are you asking only for multi-line titles to be left-aligned, and for single-line titles to be centered?

Both should be left aligned. With the code from the MWE above single-line titles are already left-aligned, which is why I didn't include a single-line example. Sorry for the confusion.
